# Django: Where to write querysets in Django Application?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-queryset

I know this is a type of theoretical question, but I am new to Django and I have been struggling for last 2 weeks, and it would be helpful for beginners of Django.

In the django documentation, there is a lot of information about queryset, filters, annotate, aggregate and so on. Everything mentioned there is just in command line.

But I am not able to find where do we write these queries? either in views.py, models.py or somewhere else.

For example, I am making a django application, where I have two models `Client` and `Installment`, and each client can have multiple installments, so they are connected with foreign key.

Now, I am able to do most of the tasks like, adding new client, displaying list of clients, adding new installment for each client, displaying the list of installments of each particular client.

I am using 'Class based Views' in my views.py, and I have one view called `InstallmentListView`

views.py

```
class InstallmentListView(ListView):
    model = Installment
    template_name = 'client_management_system/installment_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'installments'

    # This function is to show the installments of the client, the details of which we are seeing currently, and
    # pk=self.kwargs['pk'] is to get the client id/pk from URL
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(Client, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return Installment.objects.filter(client=user)
```

and the html for displaying list of installments is given below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "client_management_system/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<body>
  <legend class="border-bottom mb-4"><h5>Installment History</h5></legend>
  <article class="media content-section">
    <div>
      <table id="installmentTable" style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <th style="width:150px">Date</th>
          <th style="width:250px">Installment Month</th>
          <th style="width:170px">Amount</th>
          <th style="width:100px">Balance</th>
        </tr>
        {% for installment in installments %}
        <fieldset>
          <tr>
            <td>{{ installment.installment_date|date:"F d, Y" }}</td>
            <td>{{ installment.installment_month }}</td>
            <td>{{ installment.installment_amount }}</td>
            <td>{{ installment.balance }}</td>
          </tr>
        </fieldset>
        {% endfor %}
      </table>
    </div>
  </article>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

Now, I am printing the details of every installment in table, and I also want to print the sum of installments in the last column called `balance`.

first entry in the balance column has the amount of first `installment_amount`, second entry in the balance must be the sum of first and second `installment_amount`, third entry must have the sum of first, second and third `installment_amount`

Now, I know the query using aggregate to take the sum of installment amounts, but I don't know how to write that in my views.py in my application so that I can print in the html given above.

I hope that I made my doubt clear, but I would be happy to give any further information.

Comment: What is your question actually, *"How"* or *"Where"* ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My question has two parts. First "Where"? and second "How" in that particular case mentioned above.